# 301 redirecting pagination with get variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to set 301 redirects on pages that have 'page=1' in the URL to stop duplicate content issues.

e.g.

http://www.domain.com/reviews/?page=1
to
http://www.domain.com/reviews/

I've tried all of the variations I can find and can't seem to get anything to work.

```
RewriteRule ^reviews(/)?page=1$ http://www.domain.com/reviews/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?page=1 http://www.domain.com/reviews/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=1
RewriteRule ^reviews$ http://www.domain.com/reviews/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

None of these have worked. I'm not really sure what else to try.

There are multiple different sections of the site that I need to do this for:

```
reviews
news
videos
accessories
hardware
```

An overall solution to redirect all ?page=1 URLs to their relevant section would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to redirect every URI with `?page=1` to one without the query parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Or else if you want to redirect ONLY `/reviews` URI then

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(reviews)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

the question is already answered, i just would like to mention that your rules are not working because you didn't append a trailing `?` to the new url in the rewrite rule